# str_replace doesn't work with foreach

Tags: php, foreach, str-replace

My code:

```
$str = array(
        '{$string1}' => 'anything2',
    '{$string2}' => 'something1',
    '{$string3}' => '...'
);

$final = "";
$text = $_POST['content'];
foreach( $str as $key => $val ) {
      $final = str_replace($key, $val, $text);
}
```

My `$text` ofc. has `{string1}` , `{string2}` and `{string3}` itself, but it doesn't replace it with the values given in the array.

Why its not working?

Comment: What does $final return?

Comment: Did you mean to assign and not append to final? You have an =, but maybe you want .=.

Comment: @mqsoh I just need the `$_POST['content']` content to be replaced with the values in the array, I dont need to append anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does exactly what you need (without any extra loops):

```
$final = strtr($_POST['content'], $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 $final = str_replace('{'.$key.'}', $val, $text);
```

Ref : http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the different enconding, try this:

$text = utf8_decode($_POST['content']);// or utf8_encode

before loop;

Good lucky!